# How to get labels for radio button from array in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, radio-button

I have example of radiobutton [from internet](https://github.com/uit2712/Radio-Button-example-in-React-Native/blob/master/App.js). But I write below only what I used. But now I need to have labels from array of strings

> I not quite sure how i will achieve it, hope someone can help me.

**library**

```
import RadioForm, {
  RadioButton,   
  RadioButtonInput,   
  RadioButtonLabel 
} from 'react-native-simple-radio-button';
```

**labels**

```
var hobbies = [
  {label: "Teasing", value: 0},
  {label: "Catching plate", value: 1},
  {label: "Soaking in the mud", value: 2},
];
```

**view**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <RadioForm
      radio_props={hobbies}
      initial={0}
      onPress={(value) => alert(value)}}
    />
  </View>
```

> where should it go

```
{this.state.involvedFriends.map((name, key) => (
   <View>
      <RadioForm />
   </View>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make hobbies array in constructor like this:

```
//define an empty array
private hobbies = [] 

makeOtions = () => {    // call it after involvedFriends is initialized.
    this.state.involvedFriends.map((name, key) => (
        hobbies.push({label: name, value: key}}
    ))
}
```

now, you can pass hobbies to radio by `radio_props={this.hobbies}`